# searching for some content in a file accross multiple revisions

Tags: string, svn, revision-history

I would like to do the following using `svn`: Search in a file for a certain string content across the revision history? Is this possible>? How do I best go about it? 
Do I come up with a script using `svn cat -r1` and `grep` or is there some better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Svn has no direct support for this.

If it's only one file this will work, albeit slowly.

```
svn log -q <file> | grep '^r' | awk '{print $1;}' | \
  xargs -n 1 -i svn cat -r {} <file> | grep '<string>'
```

Fill in `<file>` and `<string>`
A `for` loop will also work so you can print the matching file/revision if desired.

Using a `for` loop to have some more output control (this is bash):

```
#!/bin/env bash
f=$1
s=$2
for r in $(svn log -q "$f" | grep '^r' | awk '{print $1;}'); do
  e=$(svn cat -r $r "$f" | grep "$s")
  if [[ -n "$e" ]]; then
    echo "Found in revision $r: $e"
  fi
done
```

This takes two arguments: the (path to) the file to search and the string to search for in the file.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for something along these lines, how would you recommend I print out the revision number for every match?